# Issues installing Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) on Docker Server Core 2016

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, windows-server-core

When I run the following command:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Feature -Online Windows-Identity-Foundation`

on a container based on windowsservercore, I get the following error:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name Windows-Identity-Foundation is unknown.
```

This command works on the same version of Windows 2016 Enterprise MSDN distribution. I'm assuming this is a feature decided to not include in WindowsServerCore. Does anyone know of a way to install it? All of the WIF 3.5 downloads either fail due to a certificate issue or says its not for this version of Windows.

Is it that they decided not to include the feature in WindowsServerCore? Looking for insight and/or solutions please. My need is to be able to use WIF on 2016 Server Core, but using Enterprise is likely to be a licensing concern (creating docker images should not require the consumer to use Enterprise Windows, right?)

Answer (score 1):

Please check if that KB help, not the same symptom as you have, but the explication explain your issue;

**To install Windows Foundation in Windows Core, you must apply the Minimal Server Interface. The Minimal Server Interface binaries are not present in Windows Core installation**. To obtain these binaries, you must use the Features on Demand component or an alternative installation source.

You can also install (and uninstall) features remotely from Windows Server Manager on a remote installation of Windows 8 or Windows 2012. [For information about how to do this, see the "More Information" section.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/server_core/2012/05/09/configuring-the-minimal-server-interface/)

Reference: [You can't install Windows Identity Foundation in Windows Core](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3044149/you-can-t-install-windows-identity-foundation-in-windows-core)

How to fix reference: [Configuring the Minimal Server Interface](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/server_core/2012/05/09/configuring-the-minimal-server-interface/)